# Angular template execution

Tags: angular

I have downloaded all the requirements to execute Angularjs template example but the problem when I run the template I got the following output:

[image]

instead of getting the following true template:

[image]

So please any suggestions

Regards,

Comment: check your console message

Comment: otherwise post your console message

Comment: I updated your question by moving angularjs tags to angular. AngularJs should be kepts for angular v1.

Comment: Looks like you're unable to fetch the css, you can check it in the console or under the network tab in developer tools

Comment: Still didn't get the answer, more clarifications please.

Comment: press F12 or 'ctrl + shift + J' in your browser and check what's wrong

Comment: Hi , when I run my code I got these errors: 1.Error NU1102 Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.VisualStudio with version (>= 1.0.0-preview3-22167)
  - Found 1 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 0.0.1-alpha ]

Comment: 2.Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design with version (>= 2.0.0-preview2-25332)
  - Found 17 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 2.0.0-preview1-final ],3.Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB3073 The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js" exited with code -1.

Comment: So any suggestions, Thanks.

Comment: Happy new year in advanced, I got another problem now when executing my angular app , the problem is that app is not loading and there are no errors , so any suggestions?

Comment: I mean when I run my angular app "loading ..." is just shown as output with out routing to home control , please need reply ASAP.